# Find subdirectories with find command

Tags: linux, find

On my linux machine I have a directory tree like this:

```
rootDir
|--123456789
|    |-- test
|    |-- live
|
|--234456789
|    |-- live
|
|--454354334
     |-- test
```

And I would need to find all top level directories that have **both** directories ("test", and "live") and then **delete the "test" one**. I would like to accomplish this with a single line command, if possible.

Comment: So, I suppose you've tried doing this and got stuck somewhere. What is your exact problem?

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 2 -name "test" -exec rm -rf {} \;` will delete all dir named test in the current directory and two levels down... the part of your question in which one has to look for both dir is (to me) difficult to imagine in one line. When you ask these kind of questions always say what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I know how to remove all those "test" directories with a find command, but my problem is, that I have to delete them only in a directory where I have both "test" and "live". So a simple one liner seems too complicated. I was trying to do it with piping but no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find <directory_name> -type d -exec sh -c "cd {} && [ -d live ] && [ -d test ] && echo \"Deleting test from {}\" && rm -rvi test " {} \;
```

`echo` is optional. `vi` options added to `rm` to make it verbose & interactive
When you said delete test one I am assuming only the test directory.
But if you want to delete the parent directory that contains both then try

```
find <directory_name> -type d -exec sh -c "cd {} && [ -d live ] && [ -d test ] && cd ../ && echo \"Deleting {}\" && rm -rvi {} " {} \;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have modified is slightly for my needs, so it works like this: find -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c "cd {} && [ -d test ] && [ -d live ] && rm -rvf test " {} \;